# Bootstrap vertically center text in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically center text in a div, but I can't get it working.

**The code:**

```
<div>
    <h3><i class="fa fa-cloud fa fa-3x"></i> Text</h3>
</div>
```

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for this? I tried many possibilities but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: first thought is `line-height` value is too low and second thought is that you need to set the `vertical-align` property of the icon to `middle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `vertical-align: middle` applied your icon glyph.  For example:

```
h3 .fa {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22cYh/

Answer (score 2):

This is how I ended up centering the cloud glyphicon:

**CSS**

```
<style>
    h3 {
        line-height: 48px;
    }
    span {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .glyphicon-cloud {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h3>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>
         Text
    </h3>
</div>
```

I set the `line-height` and `font-size` of the glyphicon and `h3` to the same value of `48px` and then applied `vertical-align: middle;` to the `<span>` that contained the glyphicon.

**edit:**

Taken from the [Bootstrap API website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use), you shouldn't mix classes with the `<span>`, as you seem to have:

> Don't mix with other components
>   Icon classes cannot be directly combined with other components. They should not be used along with other classes on the same element. Instead, add a nested  and apply the icon classes to the `<span>`.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Pshhh, I can't see the `inline code` because it's a block quote =)

Comment: lol sorry for the hasty edit there.  It was not showing the <span> text at all before, so adding the backtick characters makes it visible.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Nah, it's cool. I just thought it was funny since I was looking at the edit and was trying to figure out what changed.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical align goes onto the img, not the text.

Comment: The cloud is not an image, it's awesome-font.

Comment: I'm sure he meant the font-awesome glyph.  He's actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add display: inline-block